# Smooth scroll except on specific class but fontawesome icon doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script to smooth scroll to the anchor of a link where I don't want that links of images with fancybox are affected:

```
/*======================================
    =         SCROLL TO ANCHOR           =
======================================*/
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('fancybox')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

This is the HTML structure of the image link:

```
<div class="grid-item grid-item--big">
    <div class="gallery-image">
        <a href="assets/images/tour-view/grid-images/fancybox-1.png" data-fancybox-group="gallery" class="title-hover dh-overlay fancybox"><i class="icons fa fa-eye"></i></a>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script works everywhere on the page, and also over the image, when I click it the script does it job and no scroll is fired and fancybox image is opened as expected; except when I click on the font-awesome icon. In that case nothing happens.

Maybe I should edit my script, but how?
Any suggestion would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because the anchor element wrapping your font awesome icon also has the class fancybox. You will have to rely on other criteria to tell apart the fancybox image openers, and the font awesome icon links.

Comment: Thanks Terry, any suggestion about how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using a new class and assigned it only to elements that I want to scroll to.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('btn-book-tour') || $(event.target).hasClass('scrollto')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```